# Javascript Clipboard API with promises

Tags: javascript, promise, clipboard

I got text in clipboard:

```
<img class="imgclass" src="path_to_file/file.png">
```

When I run this code:

```
<div id="data_from_clipboard"></div>
<button id="btn-convert" onClick="convert_from_clipboard()">Convert</button>

<div id="image"></div>

<script>
    function convert_from_clipboard(){
        navigator.clipboard.readText()
            /*Alert for accepting access to clipboard appears, user accepts*/
        .then(text => {document.getElementById("data_from_clipboard").innerHTML = text;})
            /*Code from clipbard appears here, img is visible inside this div*/
        .then(imgsrc = document.getElementsByClassName('imgclass')[0].src)
            /*Error: "Cannot read property 'src' of undefined" pointing to above line of code*/
        .then(document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgsrc + '">')
        ;}
<script>
```

Looks like error appears because code is running even when user doesn't click "Accept" for reading from clipboard yet. Clipboard API is asynchronous, so I know I should do this with promises, but don't know, how. Can somebody point me into right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two syntax errors:

```
function convert_from_clipboard(){
    navigator.clipboard.readText()
        /*Alert for accepting access to clipboard appears, user accepts*/
    .then(text => {document.getElementById("data_from_clipboard").innerHTML = text;})
        /*Code from clipbard appears here, img is visible inside this div*/
    .then(() => imgsrc = document.getElementsByClassName('imgclass')[0].src)
        /*Error: "Cannot read property 'src' of undefined" pointing to above line of code*/
    .then(() => document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgsrc + '">')
    ;}
```

then accept the funtion as argument in your 2nd and 3rd you didn't pass the function but code, arrow function wihtout arugment look like this:

```
() => 10
() => { return 10; }
```

first is function that return value 10, and second is arrow function with block so you need to use return.

You can also use single then because you don't do any async code inside 1st and 2nd then function.

```
function convert_from_clipboard(){
    navigator.clipboard.readText()
        /*Alert for accepting access to clipboard appears, user accepts*/
    .then(text => {
        document.getElementById("data_from_clipboard").innerHTML = text;
        imgsrc = document.getElementsByClassName('imgclass')[0].src;
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgsrc + '">');
    });
```

Note that I didn't checked your code they may be other errors.